# Why is this for loop only printing out once? What is values.length

Tags: java

I'm just getting started so this is going to be a beginner question :)

I've had this lesson but there is something in the code I don't understand.

```
int[] values;

values = new int[3];

values[0] = 10;
values[1] = 20;
values[2] = 30;

System.out.println(values[0]);
System.out.println(values[1]);
System.out.println(values[2]);
```

This is the basic array lesson I understand. But he said that there is another way to print out the values. By using a `for` loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    System.out.println(values[i])
```

This is the part I don't understand.

1. What is `values.length`? Is it `3` or `2`?
2. Why doesn't it print out the values more than once?

Thnx

Comment: The length is 3. The max index is 2. And the loop prints all the values.

Comment: The length is 3: 0, 1, 2.  There are three values there.  What value were you expecting to see more than once and why?

Answer (score 1):

Since arrays in Java are zero-indexed, so an array that has `[10, 20, 30]` i.e. `10` at index `0`, `20` at index `1`, and `30` at index `2`, has a length of `3`. Simply the length is the number of elements in the array.

Now regarding why there is a single print statement here, it might be easier to visualise what the loop does.

The loop simply executes the code inside it, every time with a new value of `i`, as long as the loop condition is met.

So yo can think of this

```
for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    System.out.println(values[i])
```

to be translated to this

```
System.out.println(values[0])
System.out.println(values[1])
System.out.println(values[2])
```

But because as you can notice, the same function is used multiple times, only with a different input, we can only write the function once, and run it multiple times with different inputs through a loop.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, you should almost always use a BLOCK with a for statement, even if it only has one line within it.

So instead of:

```
for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    System.out.println(values[i]);
```

You'd do:

```
for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

By default, a for loop only runs the line immediately following it inside the loop.  The indentation is merely aesthetic.  If you want more than one line to be run, then you'd include them all within the brackets.

Many beginners skip the brackets and then later add a line to it...looking something like below, but expecting both lines to be run within the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    System.out.println("Value: "); // only this line is within the loop
    System.out.println(values[i]); // this line is simply indented, and stands alone
```

You can avoid some lost time troubleshooting weird problems from code like above by starting with good habits and always add brackets to your for loops.